# writing STDIN of bash application from c program

Tags: c, linux, bash, stdin

I would like to open an bash application(prog1) and send command to that application with C program.
I tried and wrote the following code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    FILE * fp;
    char message[10] = "command1\n";
    fp = popen("sudo prog1","r");
    write(STDIN_FILENO, message, 10);
    pclose(fp);
    execlp("sudo prog1", "sudo prog1", "-l", NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

This code gives an output:

```
Linux:~$ ./ prog 2 // running the code
command            // prints "command"
prog1->            // Then opens "prog1" (prog1 waits for user commands)
```

But I want it to be

```
Linux:~$ ./ prog 2 // running the code
prog1-> command    // open "prog1" and write command (instead of getting it from user)
```

It either writes after quitting **prog1** or before starting **prog1**. Please let me know how to write the "command" in **prog1**, after opening the application **prog1**. Thank you.

Note: If I make

```
fp = popen("sudo prog1","w");  //to write
```

It throws the following error
    **tcgetattr : Inappropriate ioctl for device**

Comment: How about writing to STDIN of the program you start, instead of to your own? That should do it. Also, I think your `execlp` is an orphan, besides you giving it bad arguments. Or do you have a program named "sudo prog1"?

Comment: I have a program named "prog1" but if I don't include "sudo" it says "cannot open file: permission denied"

Comment: That's a permissions issue and tangential to the question you asked. Did you create prog1 as root before you started working as a regular user? sudo gives you root privs for a command scope. You probably need to "sudo chown <myuser> prog1" where <myuser> is your username.

Comment: @user2216209: Please read a bit more careful. `execlp` expects you to parse the ommand line, so it tries to execute the program called "sudo prog1" if you ask it. That means, the program name contains a space!

Comment: @Deduplicator: I removed "execlp" from the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main bug is thinking that popen() somehow associates your child process with your STDIN_FILENO. It doesn't. STDIN_FILENO is not associated with your "sudo prog1" child. You'd have to create a pipe, dup the descriptors to stdin/stdout, and fork+exec to do that. But you used popen() so don't do that either.

Instead, you should be writing and reading from fp.

Something like:

```
  fprintf(fp, message);
  fgets(response, 100, fp);
```

Since fprintf() is buffered, you should use \n at the end of the line, or fflush().

Also, there is no point is using exec/execlp at the end when you've already called popen(). Looks like you may be mixing two approaches that you've seen by example.

popen() essentially does a combination of (pipe, dup stdin/stdout/stderr, fork, execl) to take care of redirecting a child process to a file stream connected to the parent. So no need to reimplement unless you need different semantics than popen().

You technically are implementing "expect" functionality, so you might want to look into expect, or expect modules for different languages. Expect is included with Linux distributions but is usually optional.

http://expect.sourceforge.net/

http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.21/Expect.pod

And not to mention, Perl has a Sudo module already.

http://search.cpan.org/~landman/Sudo-0.21/lib/Sudo.pm

Comment: Thank you for quick and detailed response. I removed "execlp". The program works the same. I'm using C language. The fprintf and fgets doesn't help. If the popen() takes care of dup and pipe. Please let me know how I should pass the commands to the prog1?